# Powering up my external hard drive enclosure makes Windows 10 display alerts for every available drive letter, asking me to format them. Why?

Tags: external-hard-drive, format

I have a 4TB USB HD in an enclosure. When I hit Power, Windows does these things:

Makes a list of all available drive letters. I only have C, D, E, and this one which is mounted as B.
Asks what I want to do when the drive is turned on (autoplay, etc)
Tells me I need to format F: to use it... and G: and H: all the way to Z:
How can I use this drive without having to Cancel all of those different imaginary drives and having them all show up in Explorer?

I've search SE, searched the web, and realized I must not be asking the right questions... because I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: How does the partition layout of this drive look like? You may want to have a look into the partition manager

Comment: I don't know a lot about partitions. My Disk Management console tells me this:

3719.44 GB NTFS
Healthy (Basic Data Partition)

However - and I may be misunderstanding - it looks like those other letters may all be on the 'same disk.' I'm cautious, but wondering whether I can just delete those letters.

Comment: Multiple "Letters" on the same disk are called partitions. Please edit your question with your exact partition layout, either text output from `diskpart` or a screenshot of the partition manager. Also please add if the drive is supposed to contain any existing data or if you intend to create a new volume without keeping any existing data on the particular drive.

Comment: Thanks twice for your suggestions, mashuptwice. I didn't realize that formatting an external drive had created all of those drive letters on that one disk. A look in the partition manager showed me where they were, and I simply removed the extra partitions. You're awesome. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple "Letters" on the same disk are called partitions.

You can use either `diskpart` or the builtin "Disk Management" program to edit, create and delete partitions.

Be careful what you are doing when working with partitions, deleting a partition which contains data will lead to the loss of the data!